# Make a key act as a modifier when combined with another key

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard, keyboard-layout, key-mapping

I want to achieve the following effect:

- [ <kbd>Key1</kbd> pressed & held, then <kbd>Key2</kbd> pressed & released, then <kbd>Key1</kbd> released ] acts as [ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Key2</kbd> ]
- but <kbd>Key1</kbd> pressed and released act as <kbd>Key1</kbd>

So, for example :

- Press & hold <kbd>Space</kbd>, press & release <kbd>c</kbd>, release <kbd>Space</kbd> →  interpreted as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>
- Press & release <kbd>Space</kbd> → interpreted as <kbd>Space</kbd> (the <kbd>Space</kbd> press event would be generated when the key is released)

How can I achieve that?

I primarily want this in Emacs under X, but I'd like to have this everywhere, ideally both under X and on the Linux console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21970/discussion-between-empty-mind-and-gilles).