# Remapping two (simultaneous) keypresses to a single keycode

Tags: keyboard, xkb

Is it possible to use X keyboard functionality to remap two keypresses to different keycode?

I am asking because couple of keys (such as <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>P</kbd>) on my laptop don't work anymore, thus I have to use other keys (like <kbd>CAPS</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>) to replace those keys.

Losing any of those is not fun so I want to be able to simulataneously press <kbd>T</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to produce <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (or some other keycode)

This was possible using this [wonderful customizer app](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) under OSX. However I am planning to install Debian on my machine given that most of the vendors/developers are abandoning a 32bit OSX Machine.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190216/make-a-key-act-as-a-modifier-when-combined-with-another-key as well as the resulting [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21970/discussion-between-empty-mind-and-gilles) between the OP and @Gilles. In summary: logically impossible, because when `T` is pressed, how do you predict the future and decide whether or not a `N` keypress is to follow?

Comment: It is certainly logically possible as that's what I am doing in OSX using the linked utility. I believe that app checks for keypress events (only key down) that are within a certain time interval apart, say 100ms, and then registers them as simultaneous keypress and produces the desired keycode. However that utility has a kernel extension under OSX.

Comment: Yes, but you have to buffer the key down event and wait to see what's going to happen later. If nothing happens within *x* milliseconds then you deliver the buffered event. You have introduced latency. The `T` and `N` keys now respond sluggishly. To me that would be an undesirable user experience.

Comment: Yes but the question is not related to user experience. And I have not noticed that lag so far using the mentioned utility. When your keyboard is missing couple of keys you resort to some (possibly) unpleasant solutions :)

Comment: Anyway, if that's what you really want then I hope you find an answer, but I suspect it's going to involve custom software (like a custom input method). Congratulations on sticking it out what an old half-broken laptop instead of just getting a new one. [You are contributing to reducing global toxic waste.](http://www.pbs.org/frontlineworld/stories/ghana804/)

Comment: @celada I'm also interested, since I'm using key chords to simulate modifiers keys (for example, I hit F+D as an alternative to Shift,  see https://github.com/arialdomartini/dotfiles/blob/master/private.xml). This works like a charm on OSX, with Karabiner.  As I also use Linux, I'd love to setup the keyboard the same way.

Comment: Just in case anyone uses vim there is the [arpeggio](https://github.com/kana/vim-arpeggio) plugin that does just that, which only serves to highlight how sorely this functionality is missed from the linux X environment.

Comment: I use https://github.com/jasonrudolph/keyboard on my Mac and I love. There is a 'super-duper' mode. Holding down s & d at the same time allows me to do enter super-duper mode. and while I have those keys pressed, h,j,k,l are left,down,up,right. I Really hope there's a way to do this with Linux :( Still researching.